# Print a substring from many files to a single text File

Tags: powershell, substring

I need to extract the 20th to 30th letters from many files in a single folder and print the results to a text file. 
I understand i need to use `substring(20,10)` but fail at managing multiple files.
I created a working script for single file use:

```
$var = Get-Content -Path C:\testfiles\1.txt
$var.Substring(20,10)
```

But now i need to handle multiple files.
Any help?

Comment: A `foreach` loop will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work

```
#Path to directory 
$DirPath = "C:\Files"
#get all text files from above path
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $DirPath -Filter "*.txt"
#path to text file where strings are stored
$DesFile = "C:\String.txt"

#loop through all files and save to desfile
foreach ($txt in $Files)
{
    $var = Get-Content -Path $txt.FullName
    $var.Substring(20,10) | Add-Content -Path $DesFile
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.